# BeautifulSoup suppressing lxml parsing errors?

Tags: xml, beautifulsoup, lxml

I work with BeautifulSoup using lxml to parse and navigate XML files.

I noticed strange behaviour. Beautifulsoup suppresses exceptions thrown by lxml parser when reading malformed XML file (eg. truncated doc or missing closing tags).

Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup("<foo><bar>trololo<", "xml") # this will work
```

It'll even possible to call find() and navigate such broken XML tree...

Let's try reading exactly the same malformed document with pure lxml:

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.fromstring("<foo><bar>trololo<") # will throw XMLSyntaxError
```

Why is this? I know BeautifulSoup itself is not doing any parsing, it's just a wrapper library around lxml (or other parsers). But I'm interested in actually getting errors if XML is malformed, e.g. closing tags are missing. I want just the basic XML syntax validation (not interested in XSD schema validation stuff).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to replicate the behaviour you can set  *recover=True* passing the parser:

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.fromstring("<foo><bar>trololo<",parser=etree.XMLParser(recover=True)) # will throw XMLSyntaxError

print(etree.tostring(root))
```

Output:

```
<foo><bar>trololo</bar></foo>
```

If you look at the *bs4* source code in the builder directory you will see `_lxml.py` and inside that:

```
def default_parser(self, encoding):
    # This can either return a parser object or a class, which
    # will be instantiated with default arguments.
    if self._default_parser is not None:
        return self._default_parser
    return etree.XMLParser(
        target=self, strip_cdata=False, recover=True, encoding=encoding)
```

*lxml's* *HTMLParser* sets this by default so it can deal with broken html, with *xml* you have to specify that you want to try and recover.